# Checking Who has an Excel File Open In Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

Im using Powershell 4.0 on win7 64 bit, I want to see who has an excel file open, or even if the file is open.

Example. I have the excel file "test" on network drive B. If one person opens "test" I understand that will create an excel lock file looking like this "~$test.xls". 
So far I have used Test-path to verify that the excel lock file exists. Then I believe I can use Get-Acl to find the owner of that file. Is there a simpler way to find out who has an excel file open? Or will my workaround for checking the ownership of the lock file work?

Comment: Did you try to check the owner with powershell ? Please add what you have tried and what blocks you so we can help debug (you can edit your question)

Comment: I don't think there is a "simpler" way unless you're in Windows 8 and have access to the Get-SmbOpenFile cmdlet.

I think your workaround will work well enough. While I'm sure a cleaner solution exists, it's not going to be a short or easy one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still use Netapi32 based functions for achieving this.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @" 
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Netapi 
{ 

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
    public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr buffer); 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct FILE_INFO_3
    {
        public uint FileID;
        public uint Permissions;
        public uint NumLocks;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string Path;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string User;
    }

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
    public static extern uint NetFileEnum(
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string server,
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string path,
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string user,
        int level,
        out IntPtr bufptr, 
        int prefmaxlen,
        ref Int32 entriesread, 
        ref Int32 totalentries, 
        ref Int32 resume_handle); 

}
"@ 

function Get-OpenFiles
{
    [CmdletBinding()]   
    param ( [string]$Server = "localhost", 
            [string]$User = $null,
            [string]$Path = $null)

    $struct = New-Object netapi+FILE_INFO_3 
    $buffer = 0
    $entries = 0
    $total = 0
    $handle = 0
    $Level=3 # used to define the type of struct we want, i.e. FILE_INFO_3

    $ret = [Netapi]::NetFileEnum($server, $path, $user, $level,
                                  [ref]$buffer, -1,
                                  [ref]$entries, [ref]$total,
                                  [ref]$handle) 

    $files = @()
    if (!$ret)
    {
        $offset = $buffer.ToInt64()
        $increment = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::SizeOf([System.Type]$struct.GetType())

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $entries; $i++)
        {
            $ptr = New-Object system.Intptr -ArgumentList $offset
            $files += [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($ptr, [System.Type]$struct.GetType())

            $offset = $ptr.ToInt64()
            $offset += $increment
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output ([ComponentModel.Win32Exception][Int32]$ret).Message

        if ($ret -eq 1208)
        {
            # Error Code labeled "Extended Error" requires the buffer to be freed
            [Void][Netapi]::NetApiBufferFree($buffer)
        }
    }

    $files
}
```

Then you can call the Get-OpenFiles and pass a specific path name:

```
Get-OpenFiles -Path C:\Temp\EXCEL.XLSX


FileID      : 205
Permissions : 35
NumLocks    : 0
Path        : C:\Temp\EXCEL.XLSX
User        : mickyb
```

Using `Get-OpenFiles -Path C:\Temp` works too:

```
FileID      : 205
Permissions : 35
NumLocks    : 0
Path        : C:\Temp\EXCEL.XLSX
User        : mickyb

FileID      : 213
Permissions : 51
NumLocks    : 0
Path        : C:\Temp\~$Excel.xlsx
User        : mickyb
```

You could also see if a specific user has files open:

```
Get-OpenFiles -User mickyb
```

Comment: Strange thing about this code is the function works but I get no input after using     Get-OpenFiles -path C:\wmw   Not sure If im missing a log file output or something but I get no other feedback from the code after executing. It completes and blank.

Comment: Yes, it does that if it finds no open files.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the contents of the lock file to the console it should contain the name of the user who has the file locked.  You may have to make a copy of the lock file in order to read it.  I'm not familiar with PowerShell but I assume it has all the power of DOS batch files and a technique similar to what I wrote below could be created.

Here is a batch file I have added to my `SendTo` folder which allows me to right-click on an Excel file and it will show me who has the file locked.  I have tested this with `.xlsx` and `.xlsm` files.

```vb
@echo off
REM ===================================================================
REM  Put this in your SendTo folder and it will let you right-click 
REM  on an .xlsx/.xlsm  file and show you the user name in the lock file
REM 
REM  If an Excel file is locked, look to see if a hidden lock file exists.  If
REM  the file is found, make a local temp copy of it and display the contents which 
REM  should be the name of the user holding the lock.
REM ===================================================================

setlocal
set file="%1"

REM Make sure the file has a compatible extension.
if  "%~x1"==".xlsx"   goto :ExtensionIsValidExcel
if  "%~x1"==".xlsm"   goto :ExtensionIsValidExcel

echo.
echo "%~n1%~x1" is not a supported file type.
echo.
pause
exit


:ExtensionIsValidExcel

REM  If an Excel file is locked, look to see if a hidden lock file exists.  If
REM  the file is found, make a local temp copy of it and display the contents which 
REM  should be the name of the user holding the lock.

IF EXIST %~dp1~$%~n1%~x1 ( 
    ECHO f | Xcopy %~dp1~$%~n1%~x1 "%TEMP%\~temp.txt" /H /R /Y /F
    attrib -h -s %TEMP%\~temp.txt

    cls
    ECHO.
    ECHO The Excel file "%~n1%~x1" file is locked by:
    ECHO.
    REM copy the file to the console to show the user name.
    copy %TEMP%\~temp.txt con | Find /v "file(s) copied" 
    del %TEMP%\~temp.txt
) Else (
    cls
    ECHO.
    ECHO The Excel file "%~n1%~x1" file is not locked in a way this was expecting.
)
ECHO.
ECHO.
pause
```