# Net file output truncates long file paths

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

Using POSH on a Windows server (2012) I'm trying to selectively close any files that are open on certain sub-dirs; let's say anything with E:\DIR1\source*.*.

The top-level folder structure is:

```
E:\
    DIR0
    DIR1
        source
            bob
            mike
        archive
            Week
            Weekend
```

So that means that I want to shut down connections to any files in

```
E:\DIR1\source\
E:\DIR1\source\bob
E:\DIR1\source\mike
```

The code I have calls "net file" (no params) to get a list of all open connections and works with its output to create an array of seven items that looks like this:

```
194 E:\DIR0\                                user1              0     
228 E:\DIR1\...\myFile.csv                  user2              0     
227 E:\DIR1\source\files\                   user1              0     
167 E:\DIR1\...                             user1              0     
181 E:\                                     user3              0     
241 E:\                                     user1              0     
120 E:\DIR3\...                             user4              0
```

The code then splits each line into four columns (FileID, Path, User, NumLocks).  Finally, it compares the path property of each item from "net file" with the collection of paths that I'm interested in.  So while looping through the array of items, (pseudo-code):

```
foreach ($netFileOutputItem in $netFileOutput) {
    if ($netFileOutputItem.Path -in $arrayOfSubDirs) {
        net file $netFileOutputItem.FileID /close
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: if the file path is too long, then the command "net file" truncates the output, inserting "..." in the file path (see file IDs 228, 167, 120).  I don't know the full location of file IDs 228 or 167: they're somewhere in DIR1, but are they in one of the three folders of interest or not?

So, is there:

1. Any way to force "net file" to yield up a full path
2. An alternative utility to "net file" that returns the full path and ID
3. POSH code to achieve the same output, e.g. the ID of and full path to any open file

With #2 & 3, I'd also need the file ID so that I can shut down the connection with "net file" (unless there's an alternative to that as well).

Comment: Get-SmbOpenFile is the powershell equivalent.

Comment: This is a good candidate for a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885837/checking-who-has-an-excel-file-open-in-powershell

Comment: @Tav - that function was the hook into the solution I've arrived at - thank you

Comment: @Matt - I'd disagree since that is quite a long-winded solution.  Mine is far more elegant (in comparison anyway!)

Comment: "Long winded" does not make it any less of a solution. It uses the same api as net.exe to get the information in a format that actually works. If you have access to the cmdlets, like Get-SmbOpenFile, then that works well. While yours is simple _it does not work_ and the linked answer addresses that within those limits. I am glad you found something that works

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tav's suggestion of Get-SmbOpenFile, I arrived at this pipeline-tastic solution:

```
$topPath = 'E:\DIR1\source\'
Get-SmbOpenFile | `
    ? { $_.Path.Length -ge $topPath.Length} | `
    ? { $_.Path.Substring(0, $topPath.Length) -eq $topPath} | `
    select fileID | `
    Close-SmbOpenFile -Force
```

It does everything I needed it to do:

1. Returns all open files as objects
2. Filters objects on the path length being at least equal to $topPath
3. Filters objects on the first x chars being equal to $topPath
4. Selects the FileIDs
5. Pipes those FileIDs to Close-SmbOpenFile, with -Force overriding any warning.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: THose backticks are not required. It will work without them.

Comment: You can leave the new lines and indents.... Simply remove the backticks. I code the same way.